# Linear Algebra question on basis of $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to figure out why a basis for $R^3$ cannot consist entirely of vectors of the form $[x_1,~x_2,~x_3]$, where $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ (homework question).

It doesn't make any sense to me. If we have the standard basis for $R^3$ then a homogeneous system for the vectors in the standard basis would have only a trivial solution, and therefore be both in the span and linearly independent. I don't understand why this is impossible, could someone help me understand this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have such a system, then we know that $x_3 = -x_1 - x_2$ so that a vector in your set is really of the form

$$\left(\begin{array}{r} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ -x_1-x_2\end{array}\right) = x_1\left(\begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{array}\right) + x_2\left(\begin{array}{r} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{array}\right). $$

So your space really has only two basis elements: $\left(\begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{r} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{array}\right)$. This says that your space is only two-dimensional, but $\Bbb R^3$ is three-dimensional so you miss something entirely. Particularly, notice that $\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ is not in your set.

In fact, the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$ tells you that $\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ is perpendicular to *everything* in your set, so it can't possibly be in your set. The way to see that is if $\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{array}\right)$ is in your set of vectors, then $\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{array}\right) = 0$.

Alternatively, the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 0$ defines a plane in $\Bbb R^3$ so it cannot possibly span $\Bbb R^3$ (i.e. cannot have three basis vectors).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand it now. However, I'm having a little trouble fully grasping your last point. If the equation defines a plane in the 3rd dimension, doesn't that plane span that dimension or am I missing something here?

Comment: Well it defines a plane in $\Bbb R^3$ but planes are *strict* subsets of $\Bbb R^3$ and do not fill up the full space. Think of it like an infinitely large sheet of paper.

Answer (score 0):

Let:
$$
S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0 \}
$$
You've already shown that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. It's a proper subspace too; for example, it doesn't contain $(0, 0, 1)$.

Now consider any basis $B$ for $\mathbb R^3$, where each basis element of $B$ belongs to $S$. Then by closure, any linear combination of its basis elements must also belong in $S$. But then $B$ can't possibly be a basis for $\mathbb R^3$, since $\text{span}(B) \subseteq S \neq \mathbb R^3$.